# A complete Change - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, movies

Little known I was before,
Now so many do me adore.
I changed my life around you see,
Now puzzle out who I may be.

I shot that kid, the cover up.
Not quite rain, can't fill your cup.
I puzzle it out with my mind,
That explosion could have made me blind.

That man tried to start a war.
Electricity can make me sore.
Then my friends finally arrived.
I don't like my dad, you soon derived.

Plagued by dreams, house blown apart,
Maybe that plan wasn't so smart.
I'll be back soon, don't you pout,
Raise the cry, give a shout!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be,

> Robert Downey Jr.

Little known I was before,
Now so many do me adore.

> Robert Downey was little known before his role as Iron Man

I changed my life around you see,
Now puzzle out who I may be.

> He had a lot of problems before his role as Iron Man which I think he said one time saved him. I don't have a link for that just going on memory

I shot that kid, the cover up.

> US Marshals, it's the only one that I can see a possible cover up in but I don't get the kid part

Not quite rain, can't fill your cup.

> Tropic Thunder

I puzzle it out with my mind,

> Sherlock Holmes

That explosion could have made me blind.

> The nuclear explosion from the avengers is bright enough to blind someone

That man tried to start a war.

> Richard III

Electricity can make me sore.

> One of Tony Stark's enemies in Iron Man 2 used electrical whips. I feel like that would make someone sore

Then my friends finally arrived.

> Less Than Zero

I don't like my dad, you soon derived.

> I don't think he likes his father in the movie The Judge

Plagued by dreams, house blown apart,
Maybe that plan wasn't so smart.

> His house was blown up in the third Iron Man

I'll be back soon, don't you pout,
Raise the cry, give a shout!

> Captain America: Civil War will have Robert Downey Jr. in it in 2016

Comment: You're mostly there. It's not Tony Start specifically. See if you can make all the clues match up.

Comment: @AggieKidd I was thinking it's more Robert Downey Jr. but it seemed like a lot of the clues related to Tony Stark so I added that in

Comment: Well, Tony's been in a lot of things (hint hint for the rest of the items).

Comment: @AggieKidd Which clues don't match up? I've got some other ideas for some of them but I don't want to change them if they're already right

Comment: For stanzas 2 and 3, each line is a separate clue. Other than that, you could find something (or somethings) I might be referring to in the last one.

Comment: Getting there. You have some that I didn't think of but work just as well. As for the rain clue, it isn't the Judge. Where you used it later is correct.

Comment: Not quite for the "kid" and "rain" clues. For "rain" don't think of the actual movie as much as the title. As for "the kid," there is one that fits really well, I promise. Think back before the change though.

Comment: Specifically it was Iron Man 2 which featured an electrical-whip-wielding villain. Although technically, since he wears a suit, electricity can be very bad in general (though when thor electrocutes him in the avengers, quite the opposite happens).

Comment: Not quite on the kid line yet. His role was not quite as big in this one.

Comment: @SirParselot Still not it for the kid line. He shot the "kid", not him being shot as a kid.

Comment: @AggieKidd if you google Robert Downey Jr. is the movie in that list? This is bugging the crap out of me

Comment: @SirParselot Yes it is. Also on IMDB. It was a fairly big movie (I like it), but you don't think of RBjr and this movie initially. There is another huge star that was the lead.

Comment: @AggieKidd of the movies before his change with big actors as the lead I've got Air America, Natural Born Killers, and US Marshals but I don't see how any of those fit based off what I've read. I haven't seen any of them though

Comment: @SirParselot It's one of those. Want me to just edit the answer and put that line in?

Comment: @AggieKidd I don't get the kid part, but US Marshals seems like it was a bigish movie and RDJ seems to have a small role so that's my final answer. Air America doesn't seem like it was very good based off rating so I'm assuming that's not the one you like

Comment: @SirParselot It is US Marshals. RBJ tries to shoot the fugitive, and the "kid" of the team catches him, so RBJ shoots the kid as part of the whole cover up that the movie revolves around.

Comment: @AggieKidd The plot synopsis for that movie is definitely lacking regarding that detail. No wonder I couldn't figure it out.